# How costly is leaving a gap in an array?

Tags: solidity

I want just delete the element in the array but not reformat the array to close the gap

`delete array[index];`

How costly is this assuming bytes32 as the arrays type? Will it call STORAGEKILL and free ether?

Comment: why don't you write some test code and find out?

Comment: yeah will do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
contract C {
    uint[] array;
    // omitted parameters
    function func() {
        delete array[1];
    }
}
```

Leads to this snippet:

```
  tag 7         array[1]
  JUMPDEST          array[1]
  POP           delete array[1]
  PUSH 0            delete array[1]
  SWAP1             delete array[1]
  SSTORE            delete array[1]
```

Conclusion: taking Shayan's info "a 15,000 gas refund when a non-zero value is set to zero" I infer that the deletion without recompressing the array is a good way to save gas.

Comment: So far I haven't found a good way to pre-estimate the gas costs to a good precision, the best way would be to run semi-dry runs, in the sense that to have public functions and send transactions to figure out how much gas they use.

Comment: With browser-solidity you get instant feedback. The other leg is to know if you should leave gaps or what's the best pattern...

Comment: yeah but the feedback you get from browser-solidity is not quite right when you are using libraries or multi-contract smart contracts. it's alright for basic stuff

Answer (score 2):

20,000 gas when a value is set to non-zero from zero; 5,000 gas when writing to existing storage or setting a value to zero; and a 15,000 gas refund when a non-zero value is set to zero.

Comment: I'm wondering if the solidity code above does exactly this?

Comment: source please ?